# VBA Excel - topOffset after scrolling the buttons & both direction scroll not possible

Tags: excel, vba

hello I have following code, so I can scroll through my buttons in my Sheet.

```
Private Sub Scrollbar1_Change()
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim scrollValue As Integer
    
    
    scrollValue = 10
    
    
    For Each btn In Me.buttons
        btn.Top = btn.Top - scrollValue
    Next btn
End Sub
```

I have 2 problem.

1. Scrolling only possible in one direction
2. I want a topOffset of 10 to my excel (see Picture 1) but it doesnt work (see picture 2)

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

The video shows how i want it. I did it in a userform but cant implement it in sheet

[image: how should it]

**After Answer the 1. Button isnt vissible anymore and after setting gap between buttons 0 the sorting is broken:**
[image: after edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set ScrollBar Properties**

- Follow below steps to change properties

[image]

- `Scrollbar1_Change` event code

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Scrollbar1_Change()
    Dim btn As Button, i As Long
    Dim iLoc As Long, iTop As Long
    Const TOP_GAP = 10
    Const BTN_GAP = 3
    If Me.ScrollBar1.Value <> 0 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For i = 1 To Me.Buttons.Count
            Set btn = Me.Buttons(i)
            iLoc = btn.Top + Me.ScrollBar1.Value
            iTop = TOP_GAP + (btn.Height + BTN_GAP) * (i - 1)
            btn.Top = IIf(iLoc > iTop, iLoc, iTop)
        Next i
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Me.ScrollBar1.Value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update:

- Change properties of ScrollBar :

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 100 |
| Min | 0 |
| SmallChange | 1 |
| LargetChange | 1 |
| Value | 0 |

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Scrollbar1_Change()
    Dim btn As Button, i As Long
    Dim iLoc As Long, iTop As Long
    Const TOP_GAP = 10
    Const BTN_GAP = 3
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To Me.Buttons.Count
        Set btn = Me.Buttons(i)
        btn.Top = (btn.Height + BTN_GAP) * (i - Me.ScrollBar1.Value - 1) + TOP_GAP
        btn.Visible = (btn.Top > TOP_GAP)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update:

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    Dim btn As Button, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim iLoc As Long, iTop As Long, iVal As Long
    Const TOP_GAP = 10
    Const BTN_GAP = 0.5
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    iVal = Me.ScrollBar1.Value
    For i = 1 To Me.Buttons.Count
        Set btn = Me.Buttons(i)
        If i > iVal Then
            If i = 1 Or i = iVal + 1 Then
                iTop = TOP_GAP
            Else
                With Me.Buttons(i - 1)
                    iTop = .Top + .Height + BTN_GAP
                End With
            End If
            btn.Top = iTop
        End If
        btn.Visible = (i > iVal)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't. But GIF is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @taller, its not how i want actually. I posted a video to my question, that how i want

Comment: did it as gif @taller

Comment: sorry :( i have edited my question with a picture. if i now scroll down than to the top again, the 1st button is no longer visible. And the listing looks pretty funny (still gaps after every 3 button) if I put gap between buttons 0, which I would like to do.

Comment: Oh man, I'm overwhelmed, now my search function doesn't work either. So I have a TextBox where I can filter buttons, that works. But as soon as I start scrolling (which actually doesn't work properly) all the buttons are displayed again. I tried with if TextBox not empty then only scroll through filtered buttons otherwise else scroll through all...

Comment: I did all this with button generation, filtering, scrolling, scrolling through filtered buttons, all in a UserForm and it worked without any problems. Why do I have the problem when I want to implement the same functions on Sheet instead of UserForm... I wish I can send you my exceldata so you can see and check.

Comment: It would be beneficial to address one question in each post. After resolving the current issue, feel free to create a new post for any additional questions. I've test it w/o issue with `gap between buttons 0`.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwa8r.png

Comment: The alignment and vertical distribution of your buttons are not consistent. I have uploaded an additional snippet for your reference.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Ill try it self with scrolling while searching. If i cant do it will post a new post :)